# debian jessie unable to install modules and perform upgrade

Tags: python, linux, debian, upgrade, apt-get

When I am trying to upgrade the system I am getting following error.I am new to debian and have been trying to install some modules dependent on python. But it seems I cannot install any of them and even other applications can't be upgraded or updated.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bind9-host dnsutils google-chrome-stable host libbind9-90 libdns-export100 libdns100 libirs-export91
  libisc-export95 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg-export90 libisccfg90 liblwres90
14 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 49.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,414 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main google-chrome-stable i386 45.0.2454.85-1 [47.6 MB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libisc-export95 i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [146 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libdns-export100 i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [486 kB]     
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libisccfg-export90 i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [41.9 kB]  
Get:5 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libirs-export91 i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [39.0 kB]     
Get:6 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main dnsutils i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [124 kB]             
Get:7 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main bind9-host i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [71.7 kB]          
Get:8 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libisc95 i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [177 kB]             
Get:9 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libdns100 i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [734 kB]            
Get:10 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libisccc90 i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [36.9 kB]         
Get:11 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libisccfg90 i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [56.9 kB]        
Get:12 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main liblwres90 i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [54.3 kB]         
Get:13 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main host all 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [22.9 kB]                
Get:14 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libbind9-90 i386 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3 [44.9 kB]        
Fetched 49.7 MB in 22s (2,196 kB/s)                                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 29, in <module>
    import anydbm
ImportError: No module named 'anydbm'
(Reading database ... 225859 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../google-chrome-stable_45.0.2454.85-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (45.0.2454.85-1) over (44.0.2403.157-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libisc-export95_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libisc-export95 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libdns-export100_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdns-export100 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libisccfg-export90_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libisccfg-export90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libirs-export91_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libirs-export91 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../dnsutils_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking dnsutils (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../bind9-host_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking bind9-host (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libisc95_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libisc95 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libdns100_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdns100 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libisccc90_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libisccc90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libisccfg90_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libisccfg90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../liblwres90_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking liblwres90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../host_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_all.deb ...
Unpacking host (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libbind9-90_1%3a9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libbind9-90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) over (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u2) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Setting up python-ply (3.4-5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-ply (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pycparser:
 python-pycparser depends on python-ply (>= 3.2); however:
  Package python-ply is not configured yet.
 python-pycparser depends on python-ply (<< 3.5) | python-ply-yacc-3.2; however:
  Package python-ply is not configured yet.
  Package python-ply-yacc-3.2 is not installed.
  Package python-ply which provides python-ply-yacc-3.2 is not configured yet.
 python-pycparser depends on python-ply-lex-3.2; however:
  Package python-ply-lex-3.2 is not installed.
  Package python-ply which provides python-ply-lex-3.2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pycparser (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-cffi:
 python-cffi depends on python-pycparser; however:
  Package python-pycparser is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-cffi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-colorama (0.3.2-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-colorama (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-cryptography:
 python-cryptography depends on python-cffi; however:
  Package python-cffi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-cryptography (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-distlib (0.1.9-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-distlib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-html5lib (0.999-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-html5lib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-openssl:
 python-openssl depends on python-cryptography; however:
  Package python-cryptography is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-openssl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-ndg-httpsclient:
 python-ndg-httpsclient depends on python-openssl; however:
  Package python-openssl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-ndg-httpsclient (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-urllib3 (1.9.1-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-urllib3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-requests:
 python-requests depends on python-urllib3 (>= 1.9.1); however:
  Package python-urllib3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-requests (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-setuptools (5.5.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-setuptools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pip:
 python-pip depends on python-colorama; however:
  Package python-colorama is not configured yet.
 python-pip depends on python-distlib; however:
  Package python-distlib is not configured yet.
 python-pip depends on python-html5lib; however:
  Package python-html5lib is not configured yet.
 python-pip depends on python-requests; however:
  Package python-requests is not configured yet.
 python-pip depends on python-setuptools (>= 0.6c1); however:
  Package python-setuptools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-pyasn1 (0.1.7-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pyasn1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-wheel (0.24.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-wheel (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up google-chrome-stable (45.0.2454.85-1) ...
Setting up libisc-export95 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up libdns-export100 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up libisccfg-export90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up libirs-export91 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up libisc95 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up libdns100 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up libisccc90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up libisccfg90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up libbind9-90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up liblwres90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up bind9-host (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up host (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Setting up dnsutils (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u3) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-ply
 python-pycparser
 python-cffi
 python-colorama
 python-cryptography
 python-distlib
 python-html5lib
 python-openssl
 python-ndg-httpsclient
 python-urllib3
 python-requests
 python-setuptools
 python-pip
 python-pyasn1
 python-wheel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried

> *apt-get -f install*       and *sudo dpkg --configure -a*

what will I have to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the following and got it working.

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python
```

and then

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

after that I was able to upgrade the system properly and the modules were installed. Although python 3.4 was removed.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I too faced these issues. This is because somewhere Debian jessie depends on Python 2.x and when we change the default python to python 3.x we face this errrors.

What I did to solve this error?

Change the default python to python 2. No need to remove Python 3.x so that whenever we need python we can use python 3 and for system default purpose python 2.x will be used. Someday systems will switch to Python 3.x

update-alternatives --config python
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

### Selection    Path                Priority   Status

0            /usr/bin/python3.4   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.4   2         manual mode

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install `anydbm` and `ConfigParser` via pip and then try again with `apt-get -f install`.

But I don't understand why this has happened. Have you maybe deleted some packages manually?

Comment: Yes I think I might have deleted few packages from the /usr/local/bin/python directory since I was having trouble updating few modules and according to another post the default python directory was /usr/bin/python. I am trying to install "anydbm" and "ConfigParser" right now. Will update the results. Thanks!